# Filtro por rango de fechas de tipo String en Sequelize

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sequelize.js

Estoy implementando una consulta en sequelize que me permita obtener todos los datos entre dos fechas seleccionadas(desde y hasta). 
El problema es que la fecha que debo manejar no es de tipo Date, sino de tipo String.

La consulta que me estaba funcionando con una fecha de tipo Date es la siguente:

```
          if (data.desde != '') {console.log(data.desde);
                    query.push({

                        procesador_fecha: { 
                          [Op.between]: [data.desde + ' 00:00', data.hasta + ' 23:59'],
                        },

                    })
                }
```

El console.log(data.desde) me devuelve la fecha ingresada en el primer filtro, por ejemplo: "2020-01-27 14:35:12" y la fecha con la que debo comparar para poder hacer el filtro la recibo desde la base de datos como "20200130 14:35:12" que en este caso es procesador_fecha.
Cómo puedo implementar la consulta con [Op.like] para que me haga el filtro?

Agradezco vuestra ayuda,

Saludos

Comment: En qué formato están almacenados? YYYY-mm-dd?, d/m/Y?

Comment: @ffflabs, están en formato YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize permite definir atributos especiales para un modelo, de manera que un campo sea "casteado" desde su formato en BBDD al formato que tú necesites manejar en tu lógica de negocios.

Dado que en tu BBDD el campo `fecha` es un string con el formato `YYYY-mm-dd`, un valor como '2020-02-14` correspondería a la fecha  obtenida mediante

new Date('2020-02-14');

(esto en GMT, pero no metamos timezone todavía)

Supongamos que tu modelo fuera, por ejemplo, "Evento" y queres filtrar el campo `fecha` entre objetos de tipo Date mediante un parámetro definido como

```
 let eventosFebrero={
        desde: new Date('2020-02-01')
        hasta: new Date('2020-03-01') // 00:00 del 1 de marzo
 };
```

La comparación `eventosFebrero.desde < '2020-02-14'` es `false`. Lo que haces entonces es definir un [getter](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html#getters) de la forma

```
const Evento = sequelize.define('evento', {
  fecha: {
     type: DataTypes.DATE,
     get() {
       return new Date(this.getDataValue('fecha'));
     }
   }
 });
```

De cara a tu consulta, sequelize devuelve el campo `fecha` como objeto Date y no necesitas añadirle `00:00` para consultar un `between`. También puedes hacer el paso inverso cuando quieras escribir un evento en la tabla: defines un `setter` (no un Setter Irlandés) que convierta tus Date en un string:

```
const Evento = sequelize.define('evento', {
  fecha: {
     type: DataTypes.DATE,
     get() {
       return new Date(this.getDataValue('fecha'));
     },

     set(fecha) {
         this.setDataValue('fecha', fecha.toISOString().split('T')[0] )
     }
   }
 });
```

Como fecha es un objeto de tipo Date, el método `toISOString()` devuelve un string que se ve como `2020-02-01T00:00:000.000Z` y `fecha.toISOString().split('T')[0]` es `2020-02-01` que tu BBDD encontraría ideal.

No tengo métricas del costo en eficiencia de la conversión pero quiero pensar que sequelize convierte tu getter en una función dentro de la consulta en vez de traerse todos los registros y comparar de a uno.